# Выбор RADIO в зависимости от условия с помощью JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть вот такая часть формы:

```
<label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="admin" value="t" id="adminTrue"> Да
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="admin" value="f" id="adminFalse"> Нет
</label>
```

Эта форма находиться в модальном блоке DIV, который вызывается кнопкой. Но этих кнопок целая орда, а модальная форма одна, в которую я вставляю данные в зависимости от нажатой кнопки.

НО возникла проблема, если для различных кнопок различные переключатели, то возникает некий баг, убираются параметры `checked` из формы, если сначала был выбрал `#adminTrue`, потом `#adminFalse` и если снова вернуться к `#adminTrue` отметка `checked` теряется вообще.

Вот такой JS для работы с радио кнопками у меня написан:

```
if (admin == 't') {
    modal.find('input[id="adminTrue"]').attr('checked', 'checked');
    modal.find('input[id="adminFalse"]').removeAttr('checked');
} else {
    modal.find('input[id="adminFalse"]').attr('checked', 'checked');
    modal.find('input[id="adminTrue"]').removeAttr('checked');
}
```

Как исправить проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему решил немного по другому.

Сам выбор радио кнопки сделал проще:

```
if (admin == 't') {
    modal.find('input[id="adminTrue"]').attr('checked', 'checked');
} else {
    modal.find('input[id="adminFalse"]').attr('checked', 'checked');
}
```

Но добавил в обработчик события закрытия модальной формы следующий код:

```
modal.find('input[name="admin"]').removeAttr('checked');
```

Тогда все в теории стало работать верно, но встал другой вопрос, почему-то браузеры стали отображать не корректно выделенные радио, вернее вообще не отображать.

Comment: Урок на будущее - прежде чем постить вопрос для адептов нулевого уровня, попробуй включить мозг сам :)